# Search function now working in React photo gallary

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, search, photo-gallery

Working on a small application that takes a pexels api and displays photos dynamically. When I send the search request for my api to fectch based on the new params, it does actually update the page with new photos but not the ones based on the params. I though I got the search function correct, maybe it's cause I'm not using it in a useEffect? But if I did use it in a useEffect, I wouldn't be able to set it on the onClick handle. I tried to console.log the query I was getting from the onChange but it doesn't seem like it's getting the result. What am I doing wrong?

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import pexelsApi from './components/pexelsApi'
import './App.css'


const App = () => {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [nextPage, setNextPage] = useState(1);
  const [perPage, setPerPage] = useState(25);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const getImages = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      await pexelsApi.get(`/v1/curated?page=${nextPage}&per_page=${perPage}`)
        .then(res => {
          setImages([...images, ...res.data.photos]);
          setLoading(false);
        }).catch(er => {
          if (er.response) {
            const error = er.response.status === 404 ? 'Page not found' : 'Something wrong has happened';
            setError(error);
            setLoading(false);
            console.log(error);
          }
        });
    }
    getImages();
  }, [nextPage, perPage]);

  const handleLoadMoreClick = () => setNextPage(nextPage + 1)

  const search = async (query) => {
    setLoading(true);
    await pexelsApi.get(`/v1/search?query=${query}&per_page=${perPage}`)
      .then(res => {
        setImages([...res.data.photos]);
        console.log(res.data)
        setLoading(false);
        console.log(query)
      })
  }




  if (!images) {
    return <div>Loading</div>
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
          <input type='text' onChange={(event) => setQuery(event.target.value)} />
          <button onClick={search}>Search</button>
      </div>
      <div className='image-grid'>
        {images.map((image) => <img key={image.id} src={image.src.original} alt={image.alt} />)}
      </div>
      <div className='load'>
        {nextPage && <button onClick={handleLoadMoreClick}>Load More Photos</button>}
      </div>
    </>
  )
};

export default App
```

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: `https://api.pexels.com`,
    headers: {
        Authorization: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason `perPage` is stateful?

Comment: @Phil honestly, no lol. I though I might do something with it so I kept it for now but can't think of anything so I might remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue is that you've set `query` as an argument to your `search` function but never pass anything. You can just remove the arg to have it use the `query` state instead but you'll then need to handle pagination...

```js
// Helper functions
const getCuratedImages = () =>
  pexelsApi.get("/v1/curated", {
    params: {
      page: nextPage,
      per_page: perPage
    }
  }).then(r => r.data.photos)

const getSearchImages = (page = nextPage) =>
  pexelsApi.get("/v1/search", {
    params: {
      query,
      page,
      per_page: perPage
    }
  }).then(r => r.data.photos)

// initial render effect
useEffect(() => {
  setLoading(true)
  getCuratedImages().then(photos => {
    setImages(photos)
    setLoading(false)
  })
}, [])

// search onClick handler
const search = async () => {
  setNextPage(1)
  setLoading(true)
  setImages(await getSearchImages(1)) // directly load page 1
  setLoading(false)
}

// handle pagination parameter changes
useEffect(() => {
  // only action for subsequent pages
  if (nextPage > 1) {
    setLoading(true)

    const promise = query
      ? getSearchImages()
      : getCuratedImages()

    promise.then(photos => {
      setImages([...images, ...photos])
      setLoading(false)
    })
  }
}, [ nextPage ])
```

The reason I'm passing in `page = 1` in the `search` function is because the `setNextPage(1)` won't have completed for that first page load.

Comment: I understand now, I assumed if I put the query in the arg it would be able to accept the data from the state. Thank you!